# Selling apples with out cost price at loss

Tags: percentages

> A vendor loses 4 apple price on selling 36 apples. What is his loss percentage?

I assume answer as 11.11% but answer was 10%. Am I thinking in reverse direction?

Comment: No you're not. From the information you have given the answer is 11.11%. And if you reverse the direction (which you shouldn't), the loss is 12.5%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\text{The vendor loses 4 apple price on selling 36 apples}$$
$$\text{The vendor loses x apple price on selling 100 apples}$$

$$\frac{4}{x}=\frac{36}{100} \Rightarrow 36x=400 \Rightarrow x=11.11 $$

So, his loss percentage is $11.11 \%$.

Comment: thanks for the response so, Shall I go with our assumption,but the answer in book is 10%, that's what is making me feel weird..;-)